# CSS: remove dotted line in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I want to change the outline on radio button.

To do this, I apply this css:

```
input[type="radio"] { outline: 1px solid #83D2FF; }
```

It works fine in IE (for once :) ) but in Firefox, I have my blue outline and a dotted line.

I try many thing to remove it like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:-moz-focusring {outline:none;}
```

But nothing works, I already have this dotted line.

How can I remove it ?

Comment: For responsive reasons, leave the outline alone.

Comment: `input::-moz-focus-inner { outline: 0; border: 0; zoom: normal; }`

Comment: @Itay it's one of many things I have found on stackoverflow for this problem

Comment: @aldanux it doesn't work, I already have the dotted line

Comment: Kiva, can you use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there is not some other stray CSS affecting your outline on firefox?

Comment: Just me own css overload the moz-focus-inner

Answer (score 0):

Try with that. **Wild CSS warning**!

```
radio[focused="true"] > .radio-label-box {
   border: 1px dotted transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Where do you apply the .radio-label-box class ?

Comment: You don't. `.radio-label-box` is a class that Firefox uses for its styling dynamics (e.g. Browser theme). Applying that CSS rule should overwrite the Firefox defaults (e.g. dotted line we were talking about). If you're curious about the defaults, you could find them in the **userChrome.css** file, usually in your Mozilla profile folder.